# Sending data in a timer by JS WebRTC crashes when reloading before the end

Tags: javascript, node.js, timer, webrtc

I have this simple piece of code in a server.js javascript file served by node:

```
function multiStep(myConnection, data) {
    var i=0;
        var myTimer=setInterval(function() {
        if (i<data.length){
            var element=JSON.stringify(data[i]);
            console.log("mando elemento: "+element);
            myConnection.send(element);
            i++;
        }
    }, 3000);
}

//require our websocket library 
clearInterval(myTimer);
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server; 
//creating a websocket server at port 9090 
var wss = new WebSocketServer({port: 9090}); 

//when a user connects to our sever 
wss.on('connection', function(connection) {

    loadJSON(function(response) { 

//when server gets a message from a connected user 
        connection.on('message', function(message){ 
                console.log("Got message from a user:", message); 
        });
        var json = JSON.parse(response);
        multiStep(connection, json, 0);
    })
});
```

loadJSON simply loads a json data file from another web site.
When I run the client application the first time or when the timeout has ended everything goes fine. Yet if I reload the page while the timeout is not finished I get a crash when I try to use the connection of the old page on the server with report:

> /var/www/html/MATERIALI/phonegap/node_modules/ws/lib/WebSocket.js:219
>       else throw new Error('not opened');
>                  ^ Error: not opened
>       at WebSocket.send (/var/www/html/MATERIALI/phonegap/node_modules/ws/lib/WebSocket.js:219:16)
>       at null. (/var/www/html/MATERIALI/phonegap/WebRTC/server.js:36:9)
>       at wrapper [as _onTimeout] (timers.js:261:14)
>       at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:112:15)

As a matter of fact I could simply ignore the old session given the page is reloaded. How do I avoid the server to crash in these circumstances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I found the solution; function multiStep becomes:

```
function multiStep(myConnection, data) {
     var i=0;
     clearInterval(myTimer);
     myTimer=setInterval(function() {
          if (i<data.length){
               var element=JSON.stringify(data[i]);
               console.log("mando elemento: "+element);
               try {
                    myConnection.send(element);
                    console.log("mandato elemento");
               } catch(err) {
                    console.log('Websocket error: %s', err);
          }
          i++;
       } else {
       }
    }, 3000);
}
```

And it does not crash any longer.

Comment: given that I helped you get to this point, could you upvote my answer please?

Comment: You answer was actually not very useful, if you do not tall me what is the comamnd to use to test the validity of the conenction... I am afarid I had to find the solution myself to avoid the crashing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some checking along the way. Your code assumes that everything is 100%.

```
var json = JSON.parse(response);
multiStep(connection, json, 0);
```

1. You assume there is data in response (it might be empty, or contain non-json data)
2. You should also check that json is a valid array before passing it to multiStep
3. The function multiStep also assumes that `data.length` will return something numeric

This may not be the complete answer, but it should give you a start on making your code more robust.

It's probably failing at `myConnection.send(element);` but that is probably only a symptom of your lack of checking along the way (you can also check if myConnection is still valid before you send something to it)

Referring to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket, you should be able to check the `myConnection.readyState` value:

**Ready state constants**

These constants are used by the readyState attribute to describe the state of the WebSocket connection.

```
Constant    Value   Description
CONNECTING  0   The connection is not yet open.
OPEN    1   The connection is open and ready to communicate.
CLOSING 2   The connection is in the process of closing.
CLOSED  3   The connection is closed or couldn't be opened.
```

Your code will look like this now:

```
    console.log("mando elemento: "+element);
    if (myConnection.readyState === 1)
            myConnection.send(element);
    else 
            console.log("web socket not open");
```

Comment: The problem is not in the Json data. Rather, as you hinted to at the end of your post, the validity of myConnection. How do I check it so to avoid calling the send command on an unvalid connection?

Comment: Added more to the answer for you, probably you should check it, and only if it's OPEN should you attempt to send data

Comment: The problem is that I do not know how to check if the connection is open, and you did not answer to my question either.